# XCode keeps giving me "fbsdkcorekit/fbsdkcorekit.h not found" even though it's in the project.

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to implement FBSDK into my project. I already have firebase implemented, but when I try to run my project it keeps saying the framework isn't there.

I tried the step that the website gives

"Add ~/Documents/FacebookSDK to the project's Framework Search Paths setting."

But I can't even find the FrameWork Search Paths setting on the build settings tab.

I've been stuck on this one stupid part for almost two days and it's really pissed me off. I already looked through the website for solutions, but it's still not working for me.

Comment: how did you integrate the Facebook SDK?

Comment: I followed the steps here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Comment: You should be able to find the search paths like it's shown here: http://images.revealapp.com/integration_guide/add_framework_search_paths.jpg

Comment: I finally found the framework search path and currently it's this 
$(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseDatabase/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseStorage/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleParsingUtilities/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks"
Which one should I add the facebooksdk?

Comment: Added it, but I still get an error saying it's not found.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using cocoapods.

You can integrate the Facebook SDK through cocoapods:

Include these lines in your Podfile.

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.13'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.13'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.13'
```

run `pod install`